# disk space by individual user

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I have around 50 user folder under **etc/main/** folder. Now i want to get 10 large space user folder detail.
Note: I don't want sub-folder of each user..I am using Ksh script.

Example:

```
/etc/main$ ls -lrt 
user1  user2 user3 user4 user5 ......... user50
```

Expecting result:

```
9876800 user20  
9666666 user49  
8769999 user15  
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `du` and `sort`:

```
 du -sk /etc/main/* |sort -nr
```

The arguments `-sk` to `du` tell it to report usage in kilobytes, and to sum the size of all the contents of the directory instead of reporting to each file.

The arguments `-nr` to `sort` tell it to sort numerically and in reverse order so that you get the largest directory first.

Comment: if you include -d 1 that is max-depth 1, will be more good :)

Comment: @Hackaholic If you're on an OS where `du` supports that... FreeBSD does, as does SuSE, but e.g. RHEL doesn't. I don't have Solaris or HP-UX available for testing, but my memory is that they don't. That's why I used `-s` - it's more portable.

Comment: @Jenny D - can you please explain difference between below commands, I am getting different size.  etc/main/$du -s */ | sort -nr and $du -s /etc/main/* | sort -nr

Comment: @NageshwaranM Those commands look very strange to me, presumably due to markdown formatting... Could you rewrite them, using the code markes (`\``) around the commands?

Comment: @Jenny D - can you please explain difference between below commands, I am getting different size. `etc/main/$ du -s / | sort -nr` and `$du -s /etc/main/ | sort -nr` –

Comment: The first one looks at the root directory of the server (`/`), the second only at `/etc/main`.  Neither of them will show the subdirectories under `/etc/main`; in order to do that, you need to add a `*`. You can either go to `/etc/main` and write `du -s * | sort -nr` or you can write `du -s /etc/main/* |sort -nr` in order to get the file sizes of each subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

`ls /etc/main |xargs du -sk $1 |sort -rn| head -10`